# Simultaneous writes to text file from multiple computers

Tags: file, text, vbscript, simultaneous

Using VBScript, is there any way to allow for multiple simultaneous writes to a text file from multiple computers? I need to run a script from multiple computers at the same time. The script will perform a DEFRAG and save the results to a text file. After that, the script will read from the DEFRAG log file, pull the fragmentation percentage, and write it to another MASTER log file that is meant to contain these results from every computer across the enterprise. If I always only run the script from one computer at a time, then everything works find and dandy. However, once I use a distribution point to throw the script out to the enterprise, the script works perfectly up until the point where more than one computer attempts to access the MASTER log file at the same time. That's when I'm running into access denied errors and the like. Here's what I've got so far...

```
strDrivePreCheckStarted = (Year(Date) & "-" & AEZiR(Month(Date)) & "-" & AEZiR(Day(Date)) & " @ " & AEZiR(Hour(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Minute(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Second(Time)))

a=("===================================================================================")
b=("  Script started on " & strDrivePreCheckStarted)

Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2" )
Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery ( "Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem", , 48 )
For Each objComputer in colSettings 
    CompNam = objComputer.Name
    If CompNam = "" Then
        CompNam = "ComputerNameNotFound"
    End If
    CompMfr = replace(objComputer.Manufacturer,",","")
    If CompMfr = "" Then
        CompMfr = "ComputerMfrNotFound"
    End If
    CompMdl = objComputer.Model
    If CompNam = "" Then
        CompNam = "ComputerModelNotFound"
    End If
Next

Set dClient = GetObject( "winmgmts://" & CompNam & "/root/ccm:SMS_Client" )
Set result = dClient.ExecMethod_("GetAssignedSite")
mClient = result.sSiteCode
If mClient = "OLD" Then
    mClient = "SMS"
End If
If mClient = "NEW" Then
    mClient = "SCCM"
End If
If mClient = "" Then
    mClient = "UNKNOWN"
End If

c=("    Computer: " & "[" & mClient & "] " & CompNam & " (" & CompMfr & " " & CompMdl & ")")

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set strWinDir = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(0)
Set strSys32 = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(1)
Set strTempDir = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(2)
strLogsDir = "\\fileserver\shared\logs\"

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const OverwriteExisting = False

If FSO.FileExists(strLogsDir & CompNam & ".TXT") Then
    WScript.Quit
Else
    If FSO.FileExists(strLogsDir & CompNam & "_CHKDSK.LOG") Then
        WScript.Quit
    Else
        If FSO.FileExists(strLogsDir & CompNam & "_DEFRAG.LOG") Then
            WScript.Quit
        Else

            strCHKDSKStarted = (Year(Date) & "-" & AEZiR(Month(Date)) & "-" & AEZiR(Day(Date)) & " @ " & AEZiR(Hour(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Minute(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Second(Time)))

            d=("      CHKDSK Started: " & strCHKDSKStarted)

            If FSO.FileExists(strSys32 & "\chkdsk.exe") Then
                strCHKDSKReturn = objShell.Run("%COMSPEC% /c chkdsk.exe C: > " & chr(34) & strLogsDir & CompNam & "_CHKDSK.LOG" & chr(34), 0, True)
            End If

            If FSO.FileExists(strLogsDir & CompNam & "_CHKDSK.LOG") Then
                Set ChkDskLog = FSO.OpenTextFile(strLogsDir & CompNam & "_CHKDSK.LOG", ForReading, True)
                Do While ChkDskLog.AtEndOfStream <> True
                    Curline = ChkDskLog.ReadLine
                    If InStr(Curline, "KB in bad sectors.") Then
                        Curline = Trim(Curline)
                        strKBpos = InStr(1, Curline, "KB")-2
                        strBadKB = Left(Curline, strKBpos)
                        strBadKB = Trim(strBadKB)
                        If strBadKB > 0 Then
                            ChkDskFail = "Failed"
                            e=("        " & strBadKB & "KB Of Bad Sectors Found In Used Space")
                            f=("        Drive has Failed Integrity Check")
                        Else
                            ChkDskFail = "Passed"
                            e=("        " & strBadKB & "KB Of Bad Sectors Found In Used Space")
                            f=("        Drive has Passed Integrity Check")
                        End If
                    End If
                Loop
                If strBadKB = "" Then
                    ChkDskFail = "Failed"
                    e=("        Check Disk Log Existed But Was Incomplete: " & Date & " @ " & Time)
                    f=("        Drive has Failed Integrity Check")
                End If
            Else
                ChkDskFail = "Passed"
                e=("        No Bad Sectors Found in Used Space")
                f=("        Drive has Passed Integrity Check")
            End If
            ChkDskLog.Close

            strCHKDSKFinished = (Year(Date) & "-" & AEZiR(Month(Date)) & "-" & AEZiR(Day(Date)) & " @ " & AEZiR(Hour(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Minute(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Second(Time)))

            g=("      CHKDSK Finished: " & strCHKDSKFinished)

            strDEFRAGStarted = (Year(Date) & "-" & AEZiR(Month(Date)) & "-" & AEZiR(Day(Date)) & " @ " & AEZiR(Hour(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Minute(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Second(Time)))

            h=("      DEFRAG Started: " & strDEFRAGStarted)

            If FSO.FileExists(strSys32 & "\defrag.exe") Then
                strDEFRAGReturn = objShell.Run("%COMSPEC% /c defrag.exe C: -a -v > " & chr(34) & strLogsDir & CompNam & "_DEFRAG.LOG" & chr(34), 0, True)
            End If

            If FSO.FileExists(strLogsDir & CompNam & "_DEFRAG.LOG") Then
                Set DefragLog = FSO.OpenTextFile(strLogsDir & CompNam & "_DEFRAG.LOG", ForReading, True)
                Do While DefragLog.AtEndOfStream <> True
                    CurLine = DefragLog.ReadLine
                    If InStr(CurLine, "Total fragmentation") Then
                        FragPosition = InStr(1,CurLine," %",1)-2
                        CurLine = CurLine
                        strFragAmount = Right(CurLine,4)
                        strFragAmount = Left(strFragAmount,2)
                        strFragAmount = Ltrim(strFragAmount)
                    End If
                Loop
            Else
                DefragFail = "Failed"
                i=("        Log File Could not be Located. Please try Again.")
                j=("        Drive has Passed Defragmentation Check")
            End If
            If strFragAmount = "" Then
                DefragFail = "Failed"
                i=("        An Unknown Error has Occured. Please try Again.")
                j=("        Run 'DEFRAG -v' from this machine manually.")
            Else
                If strFragAmount < 30 Then
                    DefragFail = "Passed"
                    i=("        Drive is " & strFragAmount & "% Fragmented")
                    j=("        Drive has Passed Defragmentation Check")
                End If
                If strFragAmount >= 30 Then
                    DefragFail = "Failed"
                    i=("        Drive is " & strFragAmount & "% Fragmented")
                    j=("        Drive has Failed Defragmentation Check")
                End If
            End If
            DefragLog.Close

            strDEFRAGFinished = (Year(Date) & "-" & AEZiR(Month(Date)) & "-" & AEZiR(Day(Date)) & " @ " & AEZiR(Hour(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Minute(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Second(Time)))

            k=("      DEFRAG Finished: " & strDEFRAGFinished)

            strDrivePreCheckFinished = (Year(Date) & "-" & AEZiR(Month(Date)) & "-" & AEZiR(Day(Date)) & " @ " & AEZiR(Hour(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Minute(Time)) & ":" & AEZiR(Second(Time)))

            l=("  Script finished on " & strDRIVEPreCheckFinished)
            m=("===================================================================================")

            Set TXTLog = FSO.CreateTextFile(strLogsDir & CompNam & ".TXT", True)
            TXTLog.WriteLine(strDrivePreCheckStarted & "," & mClient & "," & CompNam & "," & CompMfr & "," & CompMdl & "," & strCHKDSKStarted & "," & strBadKB & "KB" & "," & ChkDskFail & "," & strCHKDSKFinished & "," & strDEFRAGStarted & "," & strFragAmount & "%" & "," & DefragFail & "," & strDEFRAGFinished & "," & strDrivePreCheckFinished)
            TXTLog.Close

            If FSO.FileExists(strLogsDir & "_FDE.CSV") Then
                Set CSVLog = FSO.OpenTextFile(strLogsDir & "_FDE.CSV", ForAppending, True)
                CSVLog.WriteLine(strDrivePreCheckStarted & "," & mClient & "," & CompNam & "," & CompMfr & "," & CompMdl & "," & strCHKDSKStarted & "," & strBadKB & "KB" & "," & ChkDskFail & "," & strCHKDSKFinished & "," & strDEFRAGStarted & "," & strFragAmount & "%" & "," & DefragFail & "," & strDEFRAGFinished & "," & strDrivePreCheckFinished)
            Else
                Set CSVLog = FSO.CreateTextFile(strLogsDir & "_FDE.CSV", True)
                CSVLog.WriteLine("Pre-Check Started,Management Client,Asset Tag,Computer Manufacturer,Computer Model,CHKDSK Started,CHKDSK Bad Sectors,CHKDSK Results,CHKDSK Finished,DEFRAG Started,DEFRAG Amount,DEFRAG Results,DEFRAG Finished,Pre-Check Finished")
                CSVLog.WriteLine(strDrivePreCheckStarted & "," & mClient & "," & CompNam & "," & CompMfr & "," & CompMdl & "," & strCHKDSKStarted & "," & strBadKB & "KB" & "," & ChkDskFail & "," & strCHKDSKFinished & "," & strDEFRAGStarted & "," & strFragAmount & "%" & "," & DefragFail & "," & strDEFRAGFinished & "," & strDrivePreCheckFinished)
            End If
            CSVLog.Close

            If FSO.FileExists(strLogsDir & "_FDE.LOG") Then
                Set InstallLog = FSO.OpenTextFile(strLogsDir & "_FDE.LOG", ForAppending, True)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(b)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(c)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(d)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(e)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(f)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(g)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(h)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(i)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(j)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(k)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(l)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(m)
            Else
                Set InstallLog = FSO.CreateTextFile(strLogsDir & "_FDE.LOG", True)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(a)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(b)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(c)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(d)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(e)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(f)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(g)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(h)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(i)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(j)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(k)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(l)
                InstallLog.WriteLine(m)
            End If
            InstallLog.Close

            FSO.DeleteFile(strLogsDir & CompNam & "_CHKDSK.LOG")
            FSO.DeleteFile(strLogsDir & CompNam & "_DEFRAG.LOG")

        End If
    End If
End If

Function AEZiR(plngValue)
    Dim pstrValue
    Dim plngChars
    Dim i
    pstrValue = CStr(plngValue)
    plngChars = Len(pstrValue)
    If plngChars < 2 Then
        For i = 1 to plngChars Step -1
            pstrValue = "0" & pstrValue
        Next
    End If
    AEZiR = pstrValue
End Function
```

What am I missing? Is this task even possible with VBScript? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As neither VBScript, nor the FileSystemObject provide locking, someone/thing else has to do it:

- a [scripting] language with proper file locks
- a data store (DBMS) that allows simultaneous access
- a programmer who uses a semaphore (e.g. a renamed file) to control the file access

In my opinion, the third option is the worst, because 
the programmer has to do all the work and to take all
the risks/responsibilities. Using a database would solve 
the problem of access control out of the box; using a
suitable language would allow a standard/non-hacking
solution.

But if you like to live in interesting times - that's
the code structure I would try to get away with:

```
While it make sense to continue (# of tries, timeout, successfully written)
  rename FileIsFree.log to FileIsLocked.log
  If success
     open FileIsLocked.log
     write to FileIsLocked.log
     close FileIsLocked.log
     rename FileIsLocked.log to FileIsFree.log
     break/exit
  End If
End While
If Not successfully written
   Panic
End If
```

ADDED: 
Some food for thought:
[discussion](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=53853)
[code](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=53692)

I hope you come to the conclusion, that using a DBMS is the better idea.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the super-speedy reply! So, it seems as though the last option you mentioned would be the simplest method. However, would that still allow the script to run, then wait (or something of the like) and check to see if it's okay to write to the currently-open file, then complete and close out?

Comment: Would you be able to expand upon that structure, you indicated above, with a bit more detail? I'm really just learning when it comes to vbscript. Thank you again.